# C++98/03 reference collapsing and cv qualifiers

Tags: c++, reference, c++03, qualifiers, c++98

The code below compiles (gcc 4.7.2 or icc 13) and produces "1 2" output. Which means that `const` qualifier is dropped, i. e., `f<int&>` has the parameter type `int&`.

Why does it happen? As I understand, according to §14.3.1.4:

> If a template-argument for a template-parameter `T` names a type “reference to *cv1* `S`”, an attempt to create the type “reference to *cv2* `T`” creates the type “reference to *cv12* `S`”, where *cv12* is the union of the cv-qualiﬁers *cv1* and *cv2*. Redundant cv-qualiﬁers are ignored.

`const` should not be dropped. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f(const T& t)
{
    t++;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    cout << a;
    f<int&>(a);
    cout << ' ' << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't find that quote in either C++98 or C++03. §14.3.1 is "Template type arguments" and has no subsection or paragraph 4.

Answer (score 5):

GCC 4.7.2 does **not** compile this when the flag `-std=c++98` is specified. In fact, in C++98 (as well as in C++03) references to references do not collapse.

An attempt to instantiate `f<int&>`, where `T = int&`, produces the following function signature (here I intentionally switch the position of the argument type `T` and the `const` specifier, which is allowed because `const T&` is the same as `T const&`):

```
void f(int& const& t) // ERROR: reference to reference is illegal
```

The above is not legal in C++98, nor in C++03. Consistently, this is the error you get from GCC 4.7.2:

```
Compilation finished with errors:
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:15:14: error: no matching function for call to 'f(int&)'
source.cpp:15:14: note: candidate is:
source.cpp:5:6: note: template<class T> void f(const T&)
source.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
source.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> void f(const T&) [with T = int&]':
source.cpp:15:14:   required from here
source.cpp:5:6: error: forming reference to reference type 'int&'
```

Nevertheless, if you use the `-std=c++11` flag, then the compiler performs reference collapsing when instantiating the template: an lvalue reference to an lvalue reference becomes an lvalue reference:

```
void f(int& const& t) == void f(int& t)
```

Here the `const` qualifier gets dropped, because **it applies to the reference**, and not to the referenced object. Since references cannot be reassigned, they are `const` by nature, which is why the `const` is considered superfluous and removed. See **[this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425182/question-about-c0x-reference-collapse)** for an explanation.

That yields an lvalue reference to an lvalue reference, which resolves into a simple lvalue reference. Hence, the signature on the right side is instantiated.

The above is a viable candidate to resolve the call for `f<int&>(a)` and, therefore, it compiles without errors.

Comment: How can `void f(const int& t) { t++; }` compile? It modifies `t` which is a const reference.

Comment: Rather than assuming c++11 by default, the code above has been working for some time in gcc as an extension (it compiles in the default mode in 4.1, but fails if you ask for `-ansi`.

Comment: @Kleist: The function in the comment should not compile.

Comment: @Kleist: I think I fixed  the explanation.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thank you for clarifying. I removed that part of the sentence and fixed the explanation.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yes, it makes sense now. Especially the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4494126/164277 from your link makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is 1770 where the quote in question seems to originate:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1770.html

> 14.3.1 - Template type arguments
>
> -4- If a template-argument for a template-parameter T names a type "lvalue-reference to cv1 S," an attempt to create the type "(lvalue or rvalue) reference to cv2 T" creates the type "lvalue-reference to cv12 S," where cv12 is the union of the cv-qualifiers cv1 and cv2. If the template-argument names a type "rvalue-reference to cv1 S," an attempt to create the type "lvalue-reference to cv2 T" creates the type "lvalue-reference to cv12 S." If the template-argument names a type "rvalue-reference to cv1 S," an attempt to create the type "rvalue-reference to cv2 T" creates the type "rvalue-reference to cv12 S." Redundant cv-qualifiers are ignored.

Here is 2118 where the quote has been struck out:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html

> 14.3.1 - Template type arguments
>
> -4- If a template-argument for a template-parameter T names a type <s>"reference to cv1 S"</s> that is a reference to a type A, an attempt to create the type <s>"reference to cv2 T"</s> "lvalue-reference to cv T" creates the type <s>"reference to cv12 S", where cv12 is the union of the cv-qualifiers cv1 and cv2. Redundant cv-qualifiers are ignored</s> "lvalue-reference to A", while an attempt to create the type "rvalue-reference to cv T" creates the type T.

What you are quoting seems to be obsolete wording.

Comment: Note: In the final version of C++11, this ended up being in 8.3.2/5 (i.e. part of the dcl.ref section, no longer of temp.arg.type). The wording is unchanged apart from names.